# Getting XML data from URL with PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

New to working with XML in PHP. The following example, which was given as a solution to a prior question of a similar issue, is supposed to be working correctly. I'm not having any PHP errors come up upon loading the page, however, I am not seeing anything being displayed (the array). Been looking at example after example and can't for the life of me figure this out. I'm wondering if PHP is seeing that maybe the URL could be taking a little bit to load and is not waiting long enough?

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=12&    apiKey=2hkhej72gxyas3ky6hhjtsga&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&customerIpAddress=10.184.2.9&customerSessionId=&xml=<HotelListRequest><arrivalDate>01/22/2012</arrivalDate><departureDate>01/24/2012</departureDate><RoomGroup><Room><numberOfAdults>1</numberOfAdults><numberOfChildren>1</numberOfChildren><childAges>4</childAges></Room></RoomGroup><city>Amsterdam</city><countryCode>NL</countryCode><supplierCacheTolerance>MED</supplierCacheTolerance></HotelListRequest> ';

$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($xml);
```

Any feedback would be great. Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out $url.

You have a space inbetween the '&' and 'apiKey', remove that, first off.

I'm getting this:

```
<ns2:HotelListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://v3.hotel.wsapi.ean.com/">
  <EanWsError>
    <itineraryId>-1</itineraryId>
    <handling>RECOVERABLE</handling>
    <category>DATA_VALIDATION</category>
    <exceptionConditionId>-1</exceptionConditionId>
    <presentationMessage>
        Data in this request could not be validated: Specified arrival date is prior to today's date.
    </presentationMessage>
    <verboseMessage>
        Data in this request could not be validated: Specified arrival date is prior to today's date.
    </verboseMessage>
    <ServerInfo instance="71" timestamp="1394560288" serverTime="12:51:28.803-0500"/>
  </EanWsError>
  <customerSessionId>0ABAAA47-1A0E-8A91-44B2-24409C793B7A</customerSessionId>
</ns2:HotelListResponse>
```

**Edit:** 
With this php code:

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=12&';
$url.= 'apiKey=2hkhej72gxyas3ky6hhjtsga&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD';
$url.= '&customerIpAddress=10.184.2.9&customerSessionId=&xml=<HotelListRequest>';  
$url.= '<arrivalDate>01/22/2012</arrivalDate><departureDate>01/24/2012</departureDate><RoomGroup>';
$url.= '<Room><numberOfAdults>1</numberOfAdults><numberOfChildren>1</numberOfChildren>';
$url.= '<childAges>4</childAges></Room></RoomGroup><city>Amsterdam</city><countryCode>NL</countryCode>'; 
$url.= '<supplierCacheTolerance>MED</supplierCacheTolerance></HotelListRequest>';

$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($xml);
```

I am getting this result:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) { ["EanWsError"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (7) { ["itineraryId"]=> string(2)     "-1" ["handling"]=> string(11) "RECOVERABLE" ["category"]=> string(15) "DATA_VALIDATION" ["exceptionConditionId"]=> string(2) "-1" ["presentationMessage"]=> string(93) "Data in this request could not be validated: Specified arrival date is prior to today's date." ["verboseMessage"]=> string(93) "Data in this request could not be validated: Specified arrival date is prior to today's date." ["ServerInfo"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["instance"]=> string(3) "113" ["timestamp"]=> string(10) "1394564545" ["serverTime"]=> string(17) "14:02:25.060-0500" } } } ["customerSessionId"]=> string(36) "0ABAAA71-C7B2-7914-4B22-8599F39026A8" }
```

What makes my code different from yours is that I made absolutely sure that there were no spaces in the query url.

Comment: Yeah that was just a formatting issue when I copy and pasted. Sorry. Yes if you copy the URL directly into a browser that is what appears, however, I am not getting anything with the above PHP code...

Comment: Frustrating... Still not seeing anything. I am however seeing "bool(false)" being displayed. I am guessing that is from the "var_dump". Would the web server be causing issues with this? I am currently using ipage.